# Staying in Canada (Québec) for 4 months as a visitor

Tags: visas, canada

I need to go to Montréal for my studies.
My girlfriend wants to follow. We decided that she will stay as a tourist. 
(We're French.)

Someone told me that the maximum stay as a tourist in Canada was 3 months. However, I can't find this information online. In fact, I can't find any information about the duration of the stay.

Can she stay for 4 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most visitors to Canada can be granted a stay of [up to *six months*](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16) ([fr](http://www.cic.gc.ca/francais/centre-aide/reponse.asp?qnum=1016&top=16)) from the date of entry. But the border officer may decide to grant a shorter stay in some circumstances.

> A border services officer at the port of entry in Canada will determine how long you can stay in Canada. Most visitors are allowed a six-month stay from the day they entered Canada. If the officer authorizes a stay of less than six months, they will indicate in your passport the date by which you must leave Canada.
>
> If you want to stay longer than your authorized stay, you should apply for an extension at least 30 days before the authorized end of your stay.

---

> Un agent des services frontaliers au point d’entrée canadien déterminera combien de temps vous pouvez rester au pays. La plupart des visiteurs sont autorisés à séjourner au Canada pendant six mois après la date de leur arrivée. Si l’agent autorise un séjour de moins de six mois, il devra indiquer dans votre passeport la date à laquelle vous devez quitter le pays.
>
> Si vous souhaitez rester au-delà de la période autorisée, vous devez présenter une demande de prolongation au moins 30 jours avant la fin de votre séjour.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I get it right, she will only need an eTA ? Plus passport of course.

Comment: Right, passport and eTA. And of course money :)

Comment: Someone told me at a travel agence that she might need a roud-trip ticket to stay as a visitor. Is this true ?

Comment: Canada doesn't require return tickets, but they do require that you can afford to purchase one. You may be asked to show financial means at the border, especially for a long visit.

Comment: It's not really needed to quote the French-language version, is it?  This is an English language site.

Comment: @gerrit there are many things in this world that are not needed but are nonetheless helpful.